# Visualizing values in different columns for each row and connect them by line in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe, visualization

I have the following data frame:

```
user_id 2016-23  2016-23    2016-25
  1       10      20        30
  2       5       15        45
  3       20      11        21
  4       40      30        20
  5       40      21        17
```

I need to visualize the data frame so that i have '2016-23' , '2016-23' and '2016-25' in x axis and for connected dots  each 'user_id ' based on its value in column to see if the trend is increasing or decreasing over time.

Comment: @akrun appreciate your help

Comment: @lmo appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are looking for..

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(user_id=c(1,2,3,4,5),a=c(10,5,20,40,40), b=c(20,15,11,30,21),c=c(30,45,21,20,17))

colnames(df)=c("user_id","2016-23","2016-23","2016-25")

df<- reshape2::melt(df,"user_id",2:4)
df_res <- mutate(df,user_id = as.factor(user_id),variable=as.character(variable))
```

This results in:

```
 user_id variable value
1        1  2016-23    10
2        2  2016-23     5
3        3  2016-23    20
4        4  2016-23    40
5        5  2016-23    40
6        1  2016-23    10
7        2  2016-23     5
8        3  2016-23    20
9        4  2016-23    40
10       5  2016-23    40
11       1  2016-25    30
12       2  2016-25    45
13       3  2016-25    21
14       4  2016-25    20
15       5  2016-25    17
```

plotting the data

```
ggplot(df_res,aes(x=variable,y=value,group=user_id,colour=user_id))+geom_line()+geom_point(aes(shape=user_id))
```

[image]

if you were then looking to plot a trend line you can add `geom_smooth` as follows (since i don't have enough data points the graph results wouldn't mean anything.

```
ggplot(df_res,aes(x=variable,y=value,group=user_id,colour=user_id))+geom_line()+geom_point(aes(shape=user_id))+geom_smooth(method = "lm",aes(group=user_id))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think that would solve my problem in real data set i have more than 2500 id and i need to show the trend line for each id, what i mean with trend line is to connect the dots for each agent and show them as a line

Comment: what i mean with trend line is to connect the dots for each agent and show them as a line for example a line that shows one is started from 10 in 2016-23 and then increased to 20 in 2016-24 and then to 30 in 2016-25

Comment: I've made the changes to the answer to reflect the clarifications you've given.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Arun what if i don't want to use different shapes for the dots and just differentiate them by color?

Comment: You can remove remove the `aes(shape=user_id)` in the `geom_point`

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of legend? for 2500 id it is almost impossible to have all of them

Comment: when you are plotting add the following `+ theme(legend.position="none")`